# Some product images are not loading

Tags: product-images

We are using 1.9.1.0 on wamp 2.5. 
I have just moved the database and all the files from our live website. The only problem now is that while some product images are loading most are not loading. Any help is really welcome.

Comment: Not loading how? Is the url not found?

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache. When I first got it installed it showed magento place holder image. When I cleared the cache it started showing the default image for a broken image. When I look at the image URL it's fine. To me it seems like magento can't write my image after clearing the cache to the cage folder. It's making me pull my hair out:)

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the inconvenience, I found the solution to my own problem. I have just been comparing the media folder structure from our server to what i have on my localhost. I found that there are a lot of images missing. This is because from our Live server, folder a is different from folder A. But when you copy such structure over to a windows folder structure, it loses one of the two. In some instance for me, it had renamed A to a and didnt copy original a over.
Now i am just trying to find out about how to get around this problem.